# Kubernetes HPA : Send HPA logs as events to aws cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I am working on EKS cluster in AWS. We have an application, which is memory intensive. Because of that, I have added an HPA, which has 60% memory utilization. We would like to have only this info in cloudwatch, so we can scale our servers accordingly.  I tried container insights, but it's an overkill.

**Is there any way to get Kubernetes HPA logs in cloudwatch as events?**

HPA :

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: resize-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: magento-prod-deployment
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory 
      target:
        type: Utilization 
        averageUtilization: 60
```

Versions :

```
 kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.8", GitCommit:"9f2892aab98fe339f3bd70e3c470144299398ace", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-08-26T20:32:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.11-eks-065dce", GitCommit:"065dcecfcd2a91bd68a17ee0b5e895088430bd05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-16T01:44:47Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.17", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

EKS cluster is running on 1.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `k8s-cloudwatch-adapter` for your needs.
[Scaling Kubernetes deployments with Amazon CloudWatch metrics](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scaling-kubernetes-deployments-with-amazon-cloudwatch-metrics/) documentation provides the info on how `k8s-cloudwatch-adapter` works, how you can install and use it.

> Amazon CloudWatch Metrics Adapter for Kubernetes
>
> The k8s-cloudwatch-adapter is an implementation of the Kubernetes
> Custom Metrics API and External Metrics API with integration for
> CloudWatch metrics. It allows you to scale your Kubernetes deployment
> using the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (HPA) with CloudWatch metrics.

[k8s-cloudwatch-adapter github](https://github.com/awslabs/k8s-cloudwatch-adapter)

Please also look into [Kubernetes AWS Cloudwatch adapter not fetching custom metric value for EKS HPA autoscaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604513/kubernetes-aws-cloudwatch-adapter-not-fetching-custom-metric-value-for-eks-hpa-a) - already good example on how to enable AWS EKS autoscaling based on a custom Cloudwatch metric

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped. I have a small issue with this setup, can u please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64087291/kubernetes-hpa-hpa-not-showing-information-from-external-metrics